# Adding a body to a HttpWebRequest that is being used with the azure service mgmt api

Tags: c#, azure, configuration-files

How would i go about adding to the body of a HttpWebRequest?

The body needs to be made up of the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ChangeConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
   <Configuration>base-64-encoded-configuration-file</Configuration>
   <TreatWarningsAsError>true|false</TreatWarningsAsError>
   <Mode>Auto|Manual</Mode>
</ChangeConfiguration>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.ContentLength = buf.Length;
request.GetRequestStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

var HttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't know about Azure, but here just the general outline to send data with a `HttpWebRequest` :

```
string xml = "<someXml></someXml>";
var payload = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://foo.com");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = payload.Length;
using(var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
stream.Write(payload, 0, payload.Length);
```

If you don't *need* a `HttpWebRequest` for some reason, using a `WebClient` for uploading data is much more concise:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var result = wc.UploadData("http://foo.com", payload);
}
```

Comment: I am using portable class library and I cant find WebClient

Answer (score -1):

My book chapter showing how to use the Windows Azure Service Management API (and create the payload) can be [downloaded](http://bit.ly/wmTZ1a) for free.